# license for python MySQLdb library

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

To the best of my understanding, the python [MySQLdb](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/) library is dual-licensed, under both the GPL and the BSD-like CNRI license.  I think this because of these links:

- [Original author stating that Mysqldb is dual licensed](https://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70460/thread/9ae42ab5/)
- [One source file containing a clear dual license header](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/_mysql.c)

I am a little unclear because of:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29654381/407588) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/853337/407588).  Note that the assertion about the license of _mysql.c is currently [false](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/_mysql.c) (don't know if it was true when posted).
- The fact that there is no clear statement of an overall license in the overall readme file in the [source code](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/)

Overall, I'd say that MySQLdb is pretty clearly dual-licensed under GPL/CNRI.  **Am I wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MySQLdb is clearly dual licensed.

I had missed the overall license statement, which is in [the install file](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/INSTALL) of the original repo, rather than its README.md file.